# Copying data from one database to another database on same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to copy data from one database to another. I can do it with creating a query in one database, save the data to a spreadsheet and import into the other database but I want to find a simpler (less steps) process to do this.  Here the problem. The user name and password on the databases are not the same. Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: try using [Sql Server Import and Export Wizard](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7856Zr6fTAhUKZVAKHb7MB6IQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Fintegration-services%2Fimport-export-data%2Fimport-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard&usg=AFQjCNEfk9QG3LOclLpyUqRLNDL0WOVHiQ&sig2=JlKbSQRZYWkYMp4F-yh5zg&bvm=bv.152479541,d.bGs)

Comment: Note that you can refer to a table in another database using the syntax ? `database.schema.name`, and you can ommit `schema` if it's the same as your originating database, so for instance to grab information from a user-table in another database you could do `select * from otherdatabase..users`

Answer (score 0):

You have several options

- SQL Server import and export wizard, as mentioned above
- bcp.exe out, then bcp.exe in or bulk insert
- select * into